# Dropdown no id and no name

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I write dropdown code.

```
if (elementtype == "Id")
    new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id(element))).SelectByText(value);
if (elementtype == "Name")
    new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Name(element))).SelectByText(value);
```

But I want to select a dropdown with no id and no name

```
<div aria-posinset="0" aria-setsize="3" role="option" id=":d" 
    class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption">
    I am...
</div>
<div aria-hidden="true" class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-dropdown">&nbsp;</div>
```

This is the class I wrote

```
public static void SelectDropDown(IWebDriver driver,string element,string value,string elementtype) { 
    // SelectElement selectElement = new SelectElement(); 
    if (elementtype == "Id") new     SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id(element))).SelectByText(value); 
    if (elementtype == "Name") new     SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Name(element))).SelectByText(value); 
}
```

and I'm using it like this:

```
seleniumsetmethods.SelectDropDown(driver, "Gender", "Man", "Id")
```

I want to select mounth and gender.
https://accounts.google.com/signup?lp=1&hl=en

Comment: Please post your HTML code and show us, what exactly you want to select there. Then please show what you already tried but failed.

Comment: Page is gmail register page. I want to select gender and date mount dropdown

Comment: but both dropdowns do have an id, I don't understand why you want to select a dropdown without an id??? gender dropdown id="Gender" and month id="BirthMonth" - but these elements are no select elements in the classic sense, you probably need to click them and then choose your option

Comment: this is my class public static void SelectDropDown(IWebDriver driver,string element,string value,string elementtype)
        {
           // SelectElement selectElement = new SelectElement();
            if (elementtype == "Id")
                new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id(element))).SelectByText(value);
             if (elementtype == "Name")
                new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Name(element))).SelectByText(value);  }            this is my form code seleniumsetmethods.SelectDropDown(driver, "Gender", "Man", "Id"); this is my code but not working

Comment: @SelimErkan There's a really easy solution - give it your own class...

Comment: Is this Java or JavaScript, cause it's definitely not C#...

Comment: Er...sure? [Talk in chat.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87063/chat) Because I don't want to give away personal information right here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your own classes to the HTML code and reference to it via Java/JavaScript. Remove the C# tag cause it's not C#.

```
<div aria-posinset="0" aria-setsize="3" role="option" id=":d" 
class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption gender-dropdown"> <-- custom class
I am...
</div>
```

Also, you have the wrong month dropdown code, it's this:

```
<div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption month-dropdown"<- custom class id=":0" role="option" aria-setsize="12" aria-posinset="2">Month</div>
```

And, assuming your Java code works, then just do this:

```
if (elementtype == "Class")
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName(element))).SelectByText(value);
```

Honestly though, JavaScript is a lot easier...

```
<script>
    var gender = Document.getElementsByClassName('gender-dropdown')[0].innerHTML;

    var month = Document.getElementsByClassName('month-dropdown;)[0].innerHTML;
</script>
```

Your problem is confusing though...